# titanium alloy raised tab bar with raised center button - dailybooth style

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy

I'm trying to customize my `alloy` `TabGroup` to look like the image below (with no luck). no "height" properties on Tab item in the default documentation and with my current version of titanium 3.4.0 can't add `View` to `TabGroup`.

[image]

anybody know how to create a raised center button using alloy?

that's my index.xml view

```
<Alloy>
    <TabGroup tabsBackgroundColor="white" barColor="#f15b26" activeTabIconTint="black" tintColor="white">
        <Require src="home" nr="1" />
        <Require src="play" nr="2" />
        <Tab icon="/menu/logo.png" height="100">
            <Window title="" id="">
                <Label></Label>
            </Window>
        </Tab>
        <Require src="chat" nr="3" />
        <Require src="config" nr="4" />
    </TabGroup>
</Alloy>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use an image in the middle of the that exceed the height of the bar.

Answer (score 0):

When we implemented this solution in the past, we did a completely custom tabBar. I dont think you can accomplish what you are trying to do with the base tabBar control